# Eject button is greyed out for external hard drive on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive, eject

When right clicking my hard drive in `This PC`, there is no Eject option on the context menu.

Also the `Eject` button on the ribbon toolbar is greyed out so it won't let me click it. It only appears in safely remove hardware.

How do I  get it back so it appears?

Comment: How is the external drive connected to your PC? USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt or eSATA?

Comment: It's connected via USB